# Como inserir dados em um objeto JSON que está inserido em um arquivo .js?

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho que inserir novas cenas no final do objeto JSON (que está dentro de um arquivo .js), porém não sei como fazer a estrutura de uma nova cena de forma dinâmica/síncrona.

O que acontece. Cada cena tem *title, text, sceneId, yaw e pitch (propriedades)* com valores diferentes. E meu objetivo é criar novas cenas sem precisar inseri-las manualmente no arquivo.js.

Pensei em pegar os valores de cada propriedade (title,text,etc.) através de inputs no lado do cliente com um .hmtl e de alguma forma adicionar os dados da nova cena no final do objeto JSON?

**Tá faltando isso pra finalizar meu TCC**

**OBS: Panellum é uma biblioteca de visualização de imagens em 360**

Esse é o **arquivo .js**

````
    viewer.setPitch(viewer.getPitch() + 15);
});
document.getElementById('pan-down').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    viewer.setPitch(viewer.getPitch() - 15);
});
document.getElementById('pan-left').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    viewer.setYaw(viewer.getYaw() - 15);
});
document.getElementById('pan-right').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    viewer.setYaw(viewer.getYaw() + 15);
});
document.getElementById('zoom-in').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    viewer.setHfov(viewer.getHfov() - 15);
});
document.getElementById('zoom-out').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   viewer.setHfov(viewer.getHfov() + 15);
});
document.getElementById('fullscreen').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
viewer.toggleFullscreen();
});

//Esse é o objeto JSON que deve ser atualizado e que está dentro do arquivo.js 
viewer = pannellum.viewer('panorama', {
    "default": {
        "firstScene": "inicio",
        "author": "Paula",
        "sceneFadeDuration": 1000,
        "showControls":false,
        "compass": true,
        "northOffset": 247.5,
    },

    "scenes": {
        "inicio": {
            "autoLoad": true,
            "title": "Cristo Redentor",
            "hfov": 500,
            "pitch": 1.6473814187756146,
            "yaw": 1.8343954817635746,
            "type": "equirectangular",
            "panorama": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tour-virtual-2f2f5.appspot.com/o/img-tour%2Fchrist-redeemer.jpg?alt=media&token=479c7ed4-1041-4029-8713-c5a7988d19a3",
            "autoRotate": -4,
            "hotSpotDebug": false,
            "hotSpots": [
                {
                    "pitch": -10,
                    "yaw": -40,
                    "type": "scene",
                    "text": "Casa 1",
                    "sceneId": "casa1"
                },
                {
                    "pitch": -5,
                    "yaw": 70,
                    "type": "scene",
                    "text": "Casa 2",
                    "sceneId": "casa2"
                },
                {
                    "hfov": 110,
                    "pitch": 10.371935422677701,
                    "yaw": 177.39670728611372,
                    "type": "info",
                    "text": "Cristo Redentor é um cartão-postal famoso do Rio de Janeiro, por ser uma das Sete Maravilhas do Mundo Moderno.",
                    //"clickHandlerFunc": nodo
                }                                               
            ]
        },

        "casa1": {
            "autoLoad": true,
            "title": "Casa 1",
            "hfov": 900,
            "pitch": 10,
            "yaw": 90,
            "type": "equirectangular",
            "panorama": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tour-virtual-2f2f5.appspot.com/o/img-tour%2Fcasa1.jpeg?alt=media&token=7a76c46b-d40e-4967-9c4c-0d36373b8ae2",
            "autoRotate": -10,
            "hotSpotDebug": false,
            "hotSpots": [
                {
                    "pitch": -10,
                    "yaw": 90,
                    "type": "scene",
                    "text": "Inicio",
                    "sceneId": "inicio"
                },
                {
                    "hfov": 110,
                    "pitch": 4.829042691552391,
                    "yaw": -143.46120255227498,
                    "type": "info",
                    "text": "Rede",
                    //"clickHandlerFunc": nodo
                },
                {
                    "hfov": 110,
                    "pitch": 12.888179936636135,
                    "yaw": 30.27269057993482,
                    "type": "info",
                    "text": "Perto da Janela",
                    //"clickHandlerFunc": nodo
                },
                {
                    "hfov": 110,
                    "pitch": 10.05961813493795,
                    "yaw": 128.39392089966393,
                    "type": "info",
                    "text": "Cubo",
                    //"clickHandlerFunc": nodo
                },
                {
                    "hfov": 110,
                    "pitch": 3.9812879939194676,
                    "yaw": -91.89256054322145,
                    "type": "info",
                    "text": "Cortina",
                    //"clickHandlerFunc": nodo
                }                          
            ]
        },

        "casa2": {
            "autoLoad": true,
            "title": "Casa 2",
            "hfov": 900,
            "pitch": 3.475773155626582,
            "yaw": 1.2347982615142974,
            "type": "equirectangular",
            "panorama": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tour-virtual-2f2f5.appspot.com/o/img-tour%2Fcasa2.jpeg?alt=media&token=d7726504-ab8d-4deb-8777-7bd414ca6cdc",
            "autoRotate": -10,
            "hotSpotDebug": false,
            "hotSpots": [
                {
                    "pitch": -2.1,
                    "yaw": 0.9,
                    "type": "scene",
                    "text": "Casa 1",
                    "sceneId": "casa1",
                },
                {
                    "pitch": 14.006656151319785,
                    "yaw": -64.7948786973273,
                    "type": "info",
                    "text": "Informação",
                    //"clickHandlerFunc": nodo
                },
                {
                    "pitch": 12.947035220693715,
                    "yaw": -144.83290999490745,
                    "type": "info",
                    "text": "Informação",
                    //"clickHandlerFunc": nodo
                },
                {
                    "pitch": 13.277115445823057,
                    "yaw": 98.80455676076535,
                    "type": "info",
                    "text": "Informação",
                    //"clickHandlerFunc": nodo
                }
            ]
        },

      //As novas cenas devem ser inseridas a partir daqui.      
    }
});```
````

Comment: Você está salvar as novas cenas no JSON?
No lado do cliente você pode usar [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) para salvar os novos dados.

No servidor, você pode criar um arquivo scenes.json, e salvar as cenas lá. Se estiver usando Node.js, pode ler e escrever no arquivo usando [fs](https://nodejs.dev/learn/reading-files-with-nodejs).

Comment: André, obg pela dica.